# Node express JSON-Schema multiple fields validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Using [express-jsonschema](https://github.com/trainiac/express-jsonschema)

How to validation two fields, for example:

`("quantity" == 0 && "actualQuantity" == 0) || ("quantity" > 0 && "actualQuantity" > 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested, this will do the job:

```
{
    "anyOf" : [
        {
            "properties" : {
                "quantity" : {
                    "minimum" : 0,
                    "maximum" : 0
                },
                "actualQuantity" : {
                    "minimum" : 0,
                    "maximum" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "properties" : {
                "quantity" : {
                    "minimum" : 1
                },
                "actualQuantity" : {
                    "minimum" : 1
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You could also use `"oneOf"` instead of `"anyOf"`, but `"anyOf"` is faster with most implementations.